# ¿Como conservar los saltos de linea en DOMDocument y loadHTML?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Tengo un problema con DOMDocument, estoy recupera contenido de una pagina web para poder obtener un texto para esto estoy haciendo uso de DOMDocument y loadHTML, el texto ya lo logre recuperar, el problema es que no me respeta los saltos de linea que hay en la pagina original, no se si esto es posible o como puedo hacer que respete los saltos de linea. Este es el código que estoy usando para recuperar el texto de la pagina web:

```
<?php
        include 'simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php';
        require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        use GuzzleHttp\Client;
        use GuzzleHttp\EntityBody;
        use GuzzleHttp\Message\Request;
        use GuzzleHttp\Message\Response;
        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        set_time_limit(50000);
        $httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    
        $response = $httpClient->get('https://mx.ingrammicro.com/site/productdetail?id=081000Y');
    
        $htmlString = (string) $response->getBody();
    
        // HTML is often wonky, this suppresses a lot of warnings
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
    
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    
        $descripcion = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="margin-top-xlg hide clsEmailProductFullDesc"]');
    
        $descripcionSmall = '';
    
        foreach ($descripcion as $link) {
            $descripcionSmall = str_replace("Menos", "", $link->textContent.PHP_EOL);
        }
    
        echo $descripcionSmall;
    
        echo "<br/>*********************************<br/>";
    
        $descripcionFull = $xpath->evaluate('//div[@class="col-md-6"]');
    
        $descripcionLarge = '';
        
        foreach ($descripcionFull as $texto) {
    
            #print_r($texto);
    
            $descripcionLarge = $texto->textContent.PHP_EOL."<br/>";
            print_r($descripcionLarge);
        }
    
        echo "<br/>*********************************<br/>";
    
        $tabaFull = $xpath->evaluate('//table[@class="table font-12"]');
    
        foreach ($tabaFull as $tabla) {
            
            $tablaX = $tabla->textContent.PHP_EOL."<br/>";
            print_r($tablaX);
    
        }
?>
```

El resultado de este código es el siguiente:

> Etiqueta de dirección Brother DK1201 - 79.76mm Ancho x 28.96mm
> Longitud - Térmica - Blanco - Papel - 400 / Roll - 400 / Rollo
>
> Características Físicas MaterialPapelColorBlanco Información del
> Producto CaracterísticasTroqueladoTecnología de ImpresiónTérmicaAncho
> del Papel79.76mmLargo del Papel28.96mmNúmero de etiquetas por rollo400
> Varios CompatibilidadImpresoras de Etiquetas P-Touch de
> Brothers:QL-500QL-550QL-570QL-650TDQL-1050QL-1060NPaís de
> OrigenVietnamRecicladoNoContenido Reciclado0%% de Residuo
> Postconsumo0%Necesita MontajeNo Información General Tipo de
> ProductoEtiqueta de direcciónCódigo de FabricanteDK1201Dirección Web
> de Fabricantehttp://www.brother.comCantidad de Unidades400 /
> RolloFabricanteBrother Industries, LtdModelo de ProductoDK1201Nombre
> de ProductoEtiqueta con dirección DK1201Nombre de MarcaBrother
>
> MaterialPapelColorBlanco CaracterísticasTroqueladoTecnología de
> ImpresiónTérmicaAncho del Papel79.76mmLargo del Papel28.96mmNúmero de
> etiquetas por rollo400 CompatibilidadImpresoras de Etiquetas P-Touch
> de Brothers:QL-500QL-550QL-570QL-650TDQL-1050QL-1060NPaís de
> OrigenVietnamRecicladoNoContenido Reciclado0%% de Residuo
> Postconsumo0%Necesita MontajeNo Tipo de ProductoEtiqueta de
> direcciónCódigo de FabricanteDK1201Dirección Web de
> Fabricantehttp://www.brother.comCantidad de Unidades400 /
> RolloFabricanteBrother Industries, LtdModelo de ProductoDK1201Nombre
> de ProductoEtiqueta con dirección DK1201Nombre de MarcaBrother

El problema es que no respeta los saltos de linea, como puedo hacer para mantener estos saltos de linea?

Este es el texto que estoy intentando recuperar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que estoy recuperando el contenido de las etiquetas <div> y en el documento html original no tiene las etiquetas </br>

Comment: Si el texto fuera mio o la pagina PHP fuera mia si seria con un <div> pero estoy sacando texto de una pagina web de terceros, uso el FOR para recorer la etiqueta <div> o table para sacar el texto.

Comment: Si tenias razón ya concatene un <div> y funciona, ahora solo me falta que respete las separaciones entre las palabras. me refiero a que las junta de esta forma: Texto1Texto2 y debería ser: Texto1 Texto2

Comment: Solo agrega un espacio en blanco, debería bastar. Por que los textos si tienen su espacio...

Comment: He agregado todos los pasos descritos a la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Debes mandar el echo de php de este modo:

```
echo "Buenas, esto es una prueba </br>";
echo "para los saltos de línea de Enrique.";
```

Salida:

```
Buenas, esto es una prueba
Para los saltos de línea de Enrique.
```

---

Ahora, si tienes una variable en el `echo`
Debes concatenarle el salto de línea de todos modos.

```
$string1 = "este es un texto;
$string2 = "este es otro texto";
echo $string1;
echo $string2;
```

Salida:

```
este es un texto
este es otro texto
```

---

Para la impresión de `HTML` puedes agregar las etiquetas dentro:

```
$texto = "algún texto";
echo "<div> ".$texto" </div>";
```

Recuerda agregar los espacios necesarios para la visualización correcta.

Comment: Esto lo hago en el for que recorre las etiquetas como <div> y <table> para recuperar el contenido. pero no funciona

Comment: Entonces necesito que hagas un [example], para de ese modo, crear una réplica de impresión que necesitas

Comment: Esto me funciono pero cambie por otra función, use la librería de Goutte y se resolvió, coloco el código en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Lo logra hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Goutte\Client;

    $data_url = 'https://mx.ingrammicro.com/site/productdetail?id=081000Y';
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $data_url);

    echo "<br/>***********************<br/>";
    $crawler->filter('.p-line-2')->each(function ($node) {
        $contenidoOriginal = $node->html()."\n";
        $descripcionCorta = str_replace(array("Leer más", "..."), "", $contenidoOriginal);
        echo $descripcionCorta;
    });


    # Tabla de caracteristicas
    echo "<br/>***********************<br/>";
    $crawler->filter('#accordion')->each(function ($node) {
        $contenidoOriginal = $node->html()."\n";
        $descripcionLarga = str_replace(array("Folleto","Guías y Documentos","Descripción"), "", $contenidoOriginal);
        echo $descripcionLarga;
    });

?>
```